# error handling when performing 2 mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have constructed a function where two queries are performed. Both of these queries insert data into two separate tables, data that is related to the registration of a user.
In one table things like username,password are held and in the other table stuff like address, phone etc...
Here is the function:

```
function register_biz_user($post,$connection)

    {
    $name=$connection-> real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $lastname= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
    $pass_hashed = password::hash($_POST['password']); 

    $passwd= $connection->real_escape_string($pass_hashed);
    $buztype= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['buztype']); 
    $usertype= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['usertype']);
    $address= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $city= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $municipality= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['municipality']);
    $url= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['wwwaddress']);
    $email= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['e-mail']);
    $phone= $connection->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $hash =$connection->real_escape_string(md5( rand(0,1000) ))  ;


      $connection->set_charset("utf8");

      $result1 = $connection->query("insert into users values
      (NULL,'" .$name. "','" .$lastname . "','".$email."','". $passwd."','".                   
      $hash."','". $usertype."')");

      if (!$result1) {
          throw new Exception('error');
         return false;                                         
         }



       else{$result2=$connection->query("insert into business_users values
           ('".$connection->insert_id."','" .$address."','".$url ."','".$phone. 
             "','".$city. "','".$municipality. "','".$buztype. "')");
           }
      if(!$result2)
      {  throw new Exception('error');
          return false;}
```

return true;
        }

And here is my problem:
If you look at the code you might notice that there is the problem that  the 1st query runs without problem and the second throws an exception or **vice verca.**

My point is that there is the danger that the db WILL have ONLY partial data of the registered user. **The goal is that either both queries run successfully or none runs.**

How I must write the above code such that I can achieve the above statement?

I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: @AndyLester: "wide open"? copying a template comment message isn't always a good idea. in this case I don't see any threats..

Comment: You may want to look at changing to prepared statements instead of going through the chore of escaping everything. Prepared statements reduce the amount of cut & paste repeated code, and thus reduce the chances of making a silly mistake going forward where you forget to escape some input.

Comment: @AndyLester I will have that in mind for the next time I start writing queries, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transactions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

```
BEGIN
... queries ...
COMMIT or ROLLBACK
```

Note: "or vice verca" - that's not possible. In that case the 2nd query never gets executed.

Note2:

- what's `$post`? seems to be unused.
- why don't you use prepared statements? escaping everyhing is very error prone.
- why do you have a procedural interface, passing `$connection`? you should have objects which know about the database connections... you have mixed code for at least 3 different layers... not necessary bad if you plan to create write-once-get-rid-of-code but probably not a good idea for a project which you have to maintain for months/years.

Comment: Yes, I must see how $post will be used after all...I have not get used prepared statements, I would say it is only a matter of habit...why do you say $connection is a procedural interface...it is what gets returned from a function that makes a connection to the db using MySQLi

Comment: `$connection` is a variable. `register_biz_user` is a procedural interface (vs object oriented).. you shouldn't need to pass the connection to this method. regarding the "habit" bit... yeah, you can call best practices good habits ;)